# Cambiar color de fondo de una celda en TreeView

Tags: python, tkinter, color

Se puede cambiar el color de fondo de una celda en concreto de un treeview según la información que contenga ?? En plan que si contiene un 0 el fondo sea verde, si contiene un 1 el fondo sea naranja y si contiene un 2 el fondo sea rojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con *tags*.

Al crear el elemento `tree`, defines ciertos tags asociando a cada uno opciones de presentación (color de fondo, de primer plano, etc.) Así:

```
 self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
 self.tree.tag_configure('cero', background='green')
 self.tree.tag_configure('uno', background='orange')
 self.tree.tag_configure('dos', background='red')
```

Luego, cuando insertas los elementos en ese árbol les pones la etiqueta adecuada:

```
 etiquetas = {0: "cero", 1: "uno", 2: "dos"}
 for dato in ...:
     tag = etiquetas.get(dato)
     self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=str(dato), tags=(tag,))
```

Comment: Hola abulafia, he intentado esto que me dices pero me pone la fila entera del color correspondiente, hay alguna manera de colorear solo la celda en cuestión?

Comment: @AlfredoLopezRodes No te había entendido correctamente. Parece ser que no se puede cambiar el color de una celda individual de un Treeview, sólo por filas. Para lo que quieres una tabla como la que implementa [tkintertable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable) podría ser mejor opción

Comment: y sabes si es posible cambiar el color de la fuente en vez del fondo ??

Comment: @AlfredoLopezRodes Es lo mismo. Los atributos (color de fondo, de primerplano, o tipo de letra) de la celda individual no son accesibles. Sólo a nivel de "item" (fila, en el caso de treeview)

Comment: Vale muchas gracias.